# Is rotational kinetic energy conserved?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, torque

Physics predicts that in a system with variable radii, rotational kinetic energy is not conserved. This seems strange to me because if there is no torque applied, then there should also be no effect on the rotational kinetic energy.

Answer (score 6):

in the absence of torques, angular momentum is conserved. But when the rotating radius in a variable radius system is decreased, as for example in the classic case of an ice skater pulling in her arms, the skater is performing work on the system (muscle force travels through a distance). that work input shows up as an increase in the skater's angular kinetic energy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99222/discussion-on-answer-by-niels-nielsen-is-rotational-kinetic-energy-conserved). Only use this space to request clarification -- if there are technical inaccuracies, downvote and move on.

Comment: How can angular kinetic energy be affected by centripetal force?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no torque there is no effect on *angular momentum*.  Changing the radius will change the moment of inertia which can and will change the rotational kinetic energy.

Imagine yourself on a playground merry-go-round.  As it spins you can move towards the center but this requires work.  This work goes to increasing the rotational kinetic energy.

Since the product of moment of inertia and angular velocity must be conserved, moving so that you are half as far from the center will quadruple the angular velocity.  But, rotational kinetic energy is proportional to the moment of inertia (now  one quarter of its initial value) times the *square* of the angular velocity (now four times its initial value).  The net result  is an increase the rotational kinetic energy by a factor of four.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99224/discussion-on-answer-by-m-enns-is-rotational-kinetic-energy-conserved). Only use this space to request clarification -- if there are technical inaccuracies, downvote and move on.

Comment: How come it only increases two fold in real life?

Answer (score 1):

There *is* torque applied. Just not external torque. But internal torque can certainly take place. Just as when a spinning ballerina pulls in her arms.

Due to these internal forces and torques within this ballerina-system, energy within the system may convert to other forms. For instance between translational and rotational kinetic energy as well as between chemical energy transferred as work in muscles.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *net* torque applied. Parts of the system can create a torque to each other.

Imagine two balls in the space, with zero rotation. You are a goblin on the ball A. You touch ball B and start to rotate it.

The result: ball A will rotate. And also ball B, in the opposite direction. Thus, the net rotational kinetic energy was increased.

Comment: That is not correct. The net rotational kinetic energy is still zero. One is positive and the other is negative. That is misguided argument and does not answer the question.

Comment: @John Energy can not be negative. Specifically for rotational kinetic energy, the formula is $\frac{1}{2}\theta\omega^2$. As you can see, the sign (direction) of $\omega$ is no issue. You probably mix it with angular momentum. In my example, the angular momentum of the whole system remains of course 0, but its rotational kinetic energy grows.

Comment: I understand that your concept of energy cannot be negative. I disagree with that concept when it comes to angular energy. The fact of the matter is that angular momentum is not conserved, but I am not allowed to discuss that because you dont want to hear the truth and you cannot defeat my paper so it is best to censor me. that is why you come with this evasive nonsense.

Comment: @John Rotational kinetic energy generally is not conserved. The total energy of a closed system is conserved. And the angular momentum is conserved (what is not energy). I did not censor your question, I voted it up, I voted to "leave open", and tried to answer it.